# How do i use 3rd party MFA with Azure portal?

Tags: azure

I would like to set up 3rd party MFA with my Azure Portal login.
I tried looking at the azure active directory but not sure on how do i do this?

Could someone please assist?

Answer (score 0):

As of now there is no such feature available that you can use for the the users of your tenant during sign-in to Azure Portal. You can submit a [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/) for the same to Azure

Currently, third party authentication method is only supported for self service signup of external identities

More details and code are present in the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/code-samples-self-service-sign-up#custom-approval-workflows